# generate screenshot and send it to server (not using FileReference.upload)

Tags: apache-flex

Do you have any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this can help too, this example creates a BitmapData instance, and then sends that as a ByteArray to the server, (in my case, I was using PHP) ... you'll need to write the server side code, but there's nothing quite special here

```
package 
{
import flash.display.Bitmap;
import flash.display.BitmapData;
import flash.display.Shape;
import flash.display.Sprite;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.events.ProgressEvent;
import flash.net.URLLoader;
import flash.net.URLRequest;
import flash.net.URLRequestHeader;
import flash.net.URLRequestMethod;
import flash.net.URLVariables;
import flash.utils.ByteArray;
import mx.graphics.codec.PNGEncoder;
import mx.utils.Base64Encoder;


public class DataUpload extends Sprite
{

    private var _loader:URLLoader;

    public function DataUpload() 
    {
        // create a bitmap data
        var bd:BitmapData = createDummyImage();

        var png:PNGEncoder = new PNGEncoder();
        var ba:ByteArray = png.encode(bd);

        var b64:Base64Encoder = new Base64Encoder();
        b64.encodeBytes(ba);


        // initialize loader
        _loader = new URLLoader();
        _loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, loadCompleteHandler);
        _loader.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.PROGRESS, loadProgressHandler);

        var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest("http://localhost/YOUR_PHP_SCRIPT_URI");            
        request.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;

        var variables:URLVariables = new URLVariables();
        variables.fileData = b64;
        variables.fileName = "foobar";

        request.data = variables;
        _loader.load(request);

    }

    protected function loadCompleteHandler(event:Event):void {
        trace("complete");
    }

    protected function loadProgressHandler(event:ProgressEvent):void {
        trace("progress : ", event.bytesLoaded / event.bytesTotal);
    }

    private function createDummyImage():BitmapData {
        var bd:BitmapData = new BitmapData(300, 300, true, 0x00ffffff);

        var shape:Shape = new Shape();
        shape.graphics.beginFill(0xff0000);
        shape.graphics.drawCircle(10, 10, 10);
        shape.graphics.endFill();

        bd.draw(shape);
        return bd;
    }       

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: Use [`ImageSnapshot`](http://www.adobe.com/livedocs/flex/3/langref/mx/graphics/ImageSnapshot.html) to capture the screenshot (I assume we're just talking about the Flash screen, not the OS).  This can handle the image encoding for you, or you can capture `BitmapData` and reencode yourself.

Step 2(a): Use a [`MultipartLoader`](http://www.neerfri.com/2007/12/flex-multipartform-data-post-request.html) to post the generated bytes.  Flash security in Flash Player 10 will require the HTTP post to occur on user interaction.

or

Step 2(b): Use a regular `URLLoader`/`URLRequest` to post the generated bytes (Base64 encoded, say).